# How to redirect all urls to index.php except 1 url with htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9

I have set up htaccess to redirect all urls to homepage. Now I need one url to be exempted from that rule. How can I best do that?

The url that needs to be exempted is:

```
mywebsite.com/fulfilmentsoftware/index/cron
```

This is what i use to redirect all url to homepage:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Looking forward to hear from you guys! Thanks in advance

Comment: This is more of a DNS question then a Magento question if you ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this statement on your `.htaccess` before `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fulfilmentsoftware/index/cron
```

If you didn't modify your `.htaccess` before, the `RewriteRule` should be around line 183.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728812/301-redirect-for-all-pages-to-new-site-except-1-directory